# Centering a div vertically and horizontally

Tags: css, html, position, css-position, center

i created a maze and i want to center the smily div ("highlight_lose") to the maze ("main")

```
#highlight_lose {
    width: 550px;
    height:550px;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 50%;
    bottom: 375px;


}
```

here is the fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/30/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Answer**

Based on what you gave me, this is the required CSS code, using the old faithful position absolute method.

```
#highlight_lose {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -150px;
}
div.sad_smileyface {
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    ...
    [your graphic styling code here]
}
```

One point to note, is I set the containing div's width to 100% and centered it vertical. I then centered the child smileyface div horizontally. This isn't required, just the method I did it in. If the height changes, adjust the `#highlight_lose`, if the width changes, update `sad_smileyface`

**Original Answer**

If the height is at least decalred (which yours is), set the parent container as `position: relative` (just to make sure), you should be able to use `margin: auto;` on your child div's. This should work cross-browser to IE 6.

Other options include doing your method, by setting the margin to negative half the height and width. `margin: -275px -275px;`.

Also, CSS3's Flexbox model will fix this as well, but is heavily prefixed and not supported everywhere.

Comment: here is what heppened after i tried this: http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/32/

Comment: It worked for me, is there a way you could simplify your jsfiddle. With all those divs and effects it's hard to find the necessary divs.

Comment: here it is : http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/35/

Comment: thanks so much! finally i got a decent answer! thanksss

Answer (score -1):

http://jsfiddle.net/uqcLn/34/

Here is the new updated version, you can also set margin instead of transform for older browsers

Comment: Please attach the code within the answer

Comment: Didn't work for me at all. The smileyface is still in the corner.